# What is Ma Rainey saying on a fragment of "Trust No Man"

Tags: lyrics

Here is the link to the beautiful song *Trust no man* by *Ma Rainey*:

http://youtu.be/xoZmWPb7r1o

What is she saying from 1:50 to 2:15? The lyrics I have found omit this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't get all of it, but here's what I could get.  The things in square brackets I'm less sure about:

> Say! Take Ma Rainey's advice: Trust no man!
>   I mean [up in there] all day.
>   All right! [Y'all can believe] it.
>   Just don't trust nobody.  See where it got me, don't you?
>   He sure was [needy]

Answer (score 3):

I have just found, in Sandra R. Leib's "Mother of the blues: a study of Ma Rainey" (pag. 126), a transcription of this segment:

*"Hey, Take Ma Rainey's advice! Don't trust no man. I mean not even your own man! All right now! You'll all been [word obscure]. Don't trust nobody! See where it got me, don't you? He sure will leave."*